# SQL group by multiple columns not working

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables `MT_TRANS` and `MT_TRANS_PRODUCT`.
The structure for these two tables looks like this

```
---------------------
|   MT_TRANS        |
---------------------
|  TRANSACTION_ID   |
|  SALE_DATE        |
|  TOTAL_PAID_AMOUNT|
|  VALID            |
---------------------

---------------------
|  MT_TRANS_PRODUCT |
---------------------
|  TRANSACTION_ID   |
|  AMOUNT           |
|  PRODUCT_TYPE     |
---------------------
```

Now I want the total number of transactions for each single day. So for that, I have made my query like this

```
SELECT THEDAY, sum(TOTAL_COUNT) TOTAL_COUNT
from(
    select trunc(SALE_DAY) THEDAY,
    COUNT(*) TOTAL_COUNT
    from
    (
        SELECT TRANS.SALE_DATE,
        sum(PRD.PRODUCT_TYPE) TYPE
        from MT_TRANS,
        MT_TRANS_PRODUCT
        WHERE TRANS.TRANSACTION_ID = PRD.TRANSACTION_ID
        and TRANS.VALID = 1
        and PRD.PRODUCT_TYPE in(1,2,3)
        group by SALE_DATE,
    )
    group by trunc(SALE_DATE)
)
group by THEDAY
```

This is working fine, but here I want to add a group by `TRANSACTION_ID` also. So I added group by `SALE_DATE, TRANSACTION_ID` then it did not work.

So can someone please let me know how can I use group by both `TRANSACTION_ID` and `SALE_DATE` in the inner statement at a time?

Comment: If you will group by `TRANSACTION_ID` then your entire output will be different(not day wise count but individual transaction wise group - Not making any sense) then what you are expecting. Can you please share minimal data, expected and actual outcome?

Comment: Your `group by THEDAY` is working on the table created by the nested `select`.  That table doesn't have a `TRANSACTION_ID` field.  But will `TRANSACTION_ID` be unique across the `SALE_DATE`.  You might need to add `TRANSACTION_ID` to each `group by` and make sure you select the `TRANSACTION_ID` in each select list as well.

Comment: @Malcolm can you share some examples for the same so that I can use TRANSACTION_ID in the inner group by statement?

Comment: "Did not work" is not a constructive statement as it does not tell us what "did not work"; was there a syntax error with the query or did the query run and give you a different result to your expected output or something else? Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data; the error message relating to the code that "did not work"; and the expected output for that sample data.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to group by `TRANSACTION_ID` too which is not expected logically, I am just showing you how to do it in this answer:

```
SELECT THEDAY, TRANSACTION_ID,   sum(TOTAL_COUNT) TOTAL_COUNT
from(
    select trunc(SALE_DAY) THEDAY,
    TRANSACTION_ID,
    COUNT(*) TOTAL_COUNT
    from
    (
        SELECT TRANS.SALE_DATE,PRD.TRANSACTION_ID, 
        sum(PRD.PRODUCT_TYPE) TYPE
        from MT_TRANS TRANS,
        MT_TRANS_PRODUCT PROD
        WHERE TRANS.TRANSACTION_ID = PRD.TRANSACTION_ID
        and TRANS.VALID = 1
        and PRD.PRODUCT_TYPE in(1,2,3)
        group by SALE_DATE, PRD.TRANSACTION_ID
    )
    group by trunc(SALE_DATE), TRANSACTION_ID
)
group by THEDAY, TRANSACTION_ID
```

Comment: That was what I was suggesting

Answer (score 0):

> I want the total number of transactions for each single day.
>
> ...
>
> I want to add a group by `TRANSACTION_ID` also.

If you want the count-per-day for each `transaction_id` and also the total count-per-day across all `transaction_id`s then you can `GROUP BY TRUNC(t.sale_date), t.transaction_id` and then `COUNT(*)` to find the count for each day and `transaction_id` and then use the analytic `SUM` function over that count to find the daily total:

```sql
SELECT TRUNC(t.sale_date) AS theday,
       t.transaction_id,
       COUNT(*)
         AS count_per_id_per_day,
       SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY TRUNC(t.sale_date))
         AS count_per_day
FROM   MT_TRANS t
       INNER JOIN MT_TRANS_PRODUCT p
       ON t.transaction_id = p.transaction_id
WHERE  t.valid = 1
AND    p.product_type in(1,2,3)
GROUP BY
       TRUNC(t.sale_date),
       t.transaction_id
```